# Как сделать паузу/pause в Selenium? Selenium/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

Как через код реализовать приостановку выполнения кода? Искал решения в Интернете, но зарубежные форумы дают решение, подразумевая "pause" как sleep, т.е остановку на n секунд. А надо остановить как в плеере, до того как я сам решу продолжить выполнение. Можно было бы привязаться через `wait.until` к кнопке какой-нибудь, или полю, и ждать пока оно будет активно/заполнено. Но это разнообразно для каждой страницы.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - инициировать интерактивный ввод input-ом (к сожалению, не знаю как это на javascript). Т.е. скрипт остановится и будет ждать когда пользователь что-то введет с клавиатуры.

Если рассуждать на счет правильного метода, то какой-то каноники нет здесь, думаю. Ибо, селениум скрипты созданы быть самодостаточными и все ожидания должны "завязываться" на контент в браузере. Возможно, если вы скажете ваш кейс, то смогу предложить как реализовать через `wait.until`